# pcl::RANSAC segmentation, get all planes in cloud?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, ransac

I have a Point Cloud Library function that detects the largest plane in a point cloud. This works great. Now, I would like to extend this functionality to segment out every planar surface in the cloud and copy those points to a new cloud (for example, a scene with a sphere on the floor of a room would give me back the floor and walls, but not the sphere, as it is not planar). How can I extend the below code to get all the planes, not just the largest one?
(runtime is a factor here, so I would prefer not to just run this same code in a loop, stripping out the new largest plane each time)

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("viewer1");

    pcl::PCLPointCloud2::Ptr cloud_blob(new pcl::PCLPointCloud2), cloud_filtered_blob(new pcl::PCLPointCloud2);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>), cloud_p(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>), cloud_f(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    // Fill in the cloud data
    pcl::PCDReader reader;
    reader.read("clouds/table.pcd", *cloud_blob);

    // Create the filtering object: downsample the dataset using a leaf size of 1cm
    pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PCLPointCloud2> sor;
    sor.setInputCloud(cloud_blob);
    sor.setLeafSize(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
    sor.filter(*cloud_filtered_blob);

    // Convert to the templated PointCloud
    pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(*cloud_filtered_blob, *cloud_filtered);

    std::cerr << "PointCloud after filtering: " << cloud_filtered->width * cloud_filtered->height << " data points." << std::endl;

    pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients(new pcl::ModelCoefficients());
    pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers(new pcl::PointIndices());
    // Create the segmentation object
    pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;
    // Optional
    seg.setOptimizeCoefficients(true);
    seg.setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
    seg.setMethodType(pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
    seg.setMaxIterations(1000);
    seg.setDistanceThreshold(0.01);

    // Create the filtering object
    pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> extract;

    int i = 0, nr_points = (int)cloud_filtered->points.size();
    // While 30% of the original cloud is still there
    while (cloud_filtered->points.size() > 0.3 * nr_points)
    {
        // Segment the largest planar component from the remaining cloud
        seg.setInputCloud(cloud_filtered);
        pcl::ScopeTime scopeTime("Test loop");
        {
            seg.segment(*inliers, *coefficients);
        }
        if (inliers->indices.size() == 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "Could not estimate a planar model for the given dataset." << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        // Extract the inliers
        extract.setInputCloud(cloud_filtered);
        extract.setIndices(inliers);
        extract.setNegative(false);
        extract.filter(*cloud_p);
        std::cerr << "PointCloud representing the planar component: " << cloud_p->width * cloud_p->height << " data points." << std::endl;

        }

    viewer.showCloud(cloud_p, "viewer1");
    while (!viewer.wasStopped()) {}

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once you get the first plane, remove the points and use the algorithm to compute a new plane until either there are no points left of the estimated plane is no such thing anymore. The second case is because using RANSAC you will always find a plane as long as there are enough points. I have something similar done here (this is a callback for a ros node):

```
void pointCloudCb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr &msg){

    // Convert to pcl point cloud
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_msg (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*msg,*cloud_msg);
    ROS_DEBUG("%s: new ponitcloud (%i,%i)(%zu)",_name.c_str(),cloud_msg->width,cloud_msg->height,cloud_msg->size());

    // Filter cloud
    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZ> pass;
    pass.setInputCloud(cloud_msg);
    pass.setFilterFieldName ("z");
    pass.setFilterLimits(0.001,10000);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pass.filter (*cloud);

    // Get segmentation ready
    pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients(new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
    pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers(new pcl::PointIndices);
    pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;
    pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> extract;
    seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
    seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
    seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
    seg.setDistanceThreshold(_max_distance);

    // Create pointcloud to publish inliers
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_pub(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    int original_size(cloud->height*cloud->width);
    int n_planes(0);
    while (cloud->height*cloud->width>original_size*_min_percentage/100){

        // Fit a plane
        seg.setInputCloud(cloud);
        seg.segment(*inliers, *coefficients);

        // Check result
        if (inliers->indices.size() == 0)
            break;

        // Iterate inliers
        double mean_error(0);
        double max_error(0);
        double min_error(100000);
        std::vector<double> err;
        for (int i=0;i<inliers->indices.size();i++){

            // Get Point
            pcl::PointXYZ pt = cloud->points[inliers->indices[i]];

            // Compute distance
            double d = point2planedistnace(pt,coefficients)*1000;// mm
            err.push_back(d);

            // Update statistics
            mean_error += d;
            if (d>max_error) max_error = d;
            if (d<min_error) min_error = d;

        }
        mean_error/=inliers->indices.size();

        // Compute Standard deviation
        ColorMap cm(min_error,max_error);
        double sigma(0);
        for (int i=0;i<inliers->indices.size();i++){

            sigma += pow(err[i] - mean_error,2);

            // Get Point
            pcl::PointXYZ pt = cloud->points[inliers->indices[i]];

            // Copy point to noew cloud
            pcl::PointXYZRGB pt_color;
            pt_color.x = pt.x;
            pt_color.y = pt.y;
            pt_color.z = pt.z;
            uint32_t rgb;
            if (_color_pc_with_error)
                rgb = cm.getColor(err[i]);
            else
                rgb = colors[n_planes].getColor();
            pt_color.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);
            cloud_pub->points.push_back(pt_color);

        }
        sigma = sqrt(sigma/inliers->indices.size());

        // Extract inliers
        extract.setInputCloud(cloud);
        extract.setIndices(inliers);
        extract.setNegative(true);
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloudF;
        extract.filter(cloudF);
        cloud->swap(cloudF);

        // Display infor
        ROS_INFO("%s: fitted plane %i: %fx%s%fy%s%fz%s%f=0 (inliers: %zu/%i)",
                 _name.c_str(),n_planes,
                 coefficients->values[0],(coefficients->values[1]>=0?"+":""),
                 coefficients->values[1],(coefficients->values[2]>=0?"+":""),
                 coefficients->values[2],(coefficients->values[3]>=0?"+":""),
                 coefficients->values[3],
                 inliers->indices.size(),original_size);
        ROS_INFO("%s: mean error: %f(mm), standard deviation: %f (mm), max error: %f(mm)",_name.c_str(),mean_error,sigma,max_error);
        ROS_INFO("%s: poitns left in cloud %i",_name.c_str(),cloud->width*cloud->height);

        // Nest iteration
        n_planes++;
    }

    // Publish points
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_publish;
    pcl::toROSMsg(*cloud_pub,cloud_publish);
    cloud_publish.header = msg->header;
    _pub_inliers.publish(cloud_publish);
}
```

you can find the whole node [here](https://github.com/apalomer/plane_fitter)

Comment: Thank you! i will dig into that. So I will need to run this many times? There is no way to do this in one go, correct? Do you know if any of this functionality has been gpu accelerated in pcl? Thanks again

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way than taking each plane at a time (implemented, obviously you can implement new algorithms for such purpose). I do not know if it has been GPU accelerated or not. However, I suspect it has not. Please, if this solves your problem accept it as a good answer (not only upvote).

Comment: Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: @anti If you think it is worth, please, accept my answer as the good one (not only upvote).

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I created this method:

1) Find first plane

2) Get all points in point cloud, that are near to points in plane

3) Using linear regression approximate this points by a plane

4) Repeat 1-3 until new plane is not too small

Comment: He didn't want to run the same algo in a loop :(

Comment: So you can extrapolate RANSAC method: I suppose, that if you will choose big tolerance value, approximate extracted points to a plane if number of them is big, you will get same result with 1 iteration